# UIView animation using 90%CPU

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, animation, cpu

hi i have animation which loop but are using 90% of my iphone CPU processing and are heating up the phone. what have i done wrong ?

anybody can give me some advise ?

thanks

```
-(void)nextAnimation:(float)previousWidth {

//picture loop
imageViewTop.image = imageViewBottom.image;
imageViewBottom.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:[imageArray count] - 1];

[imageArray insertObject:imageViewBottom.image atIndex:0];
[imageArray removeLastObject];
imageViewTop.alpha = 1.0;
imageViewBottom.alpha = 0.0;

[UIView animateWithDuration:4.0
                 animations:^{ 
                     imageViewTop.alpha = 0.0;
                     imageViewBottom.alpha = 1.0;
                     } 
                 completion:^(BOOL  completed){
                     [self nextAnimation:stringsize.width];
                 }
 ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a infinite loop in you code. You must have a quit condition to avoid infinite loop. A static counter is zero, and run one time add 1, if counter > n quit.

Comment: is it because is an infinite loop that cause the high CPU ?
i need it to be looping till location are found and replace it with something else

Comment: I think maybe is, you can add a NSLog at nextAnimation to see how many time it runs, to see if it like what you want.

Comment: I didn't see any wrong infinite loop in this code. The only loop is the needed animation loop. I'm doing that kind of code every day. I think there's another problem.

Comment: not too sure, put in an NSLog, runs well
but if i tab to another view.....the NSLOG keep logging every ms

Comment: i believe is this line, if i commented it out... the CPU is fine.