# UIView repeated animateWithDuration CPU 100%

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, cpu, uianimation

Hi everyone,
small question.

I have an `UIView` class that I created, `AnimatedUIView`.
In the init, I create a subview that I animate like this:

```c
   - (void)animateView{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:4.0
                     delay:1.0
                     options: nil
                     animations:^{ 
                         // Animation PART 1
                         } 
                     completion:^(BOOL  completed){
                       [UIView animateWithDuration:4.0
                           animations:^{ 
                               // Animation PART 2
                               } 
                           completion:^(BOOL  completed){
                             [self animateView];
                           }
                         ];
                     }
     ]; 

}
```

I have to call `[self animateView]` myself in the second completion block rather than using option repeat because I want to delay 1 second only the first animation.

Everything works fine, I alloc and init my view and add it as a subview, and it is animated as should.

But, when I close my superview, I guess ARC does its work and deallocs the animatedView, but my CPU goes 100 % ! 
I have investigated and if I comment the call to `[self animateView]`, my CPU doesn't skyrocket when I close the superview.

So I've managed to solve the problem (by putting a condition before the call and changing a boolean value before closing the superview, `keepAnimating = NO`) , I just wanted to understand WHY it does this?
Why does it try to keep animating, and why does it use so much CPU? 
If I put an NSLog in the completion block, I first see it every 8 seconds, but when I close the superview, the NSLog just keeps appearing every ms...

BTW: it relates to this question : [UIView animation using 90%CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383571/uiview-animation-using-90cpu) , which was not really answered. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CPU going to 100% almost always means infinite recursion.

We can only guess because only Apple knows what's inside the animation source code.

In this case I guess this could be caused by triggering the animation when the animation cannot run anymore (e.g. there is no layer since we are in `dealloc` state). That would mean the completion handler is called **immediately** and that leads to infinite recursion.

There are safer ways to create infinite animations (e.g. using `CAAnimation` on the layer).

Comment: Thanks, this answers the question of WHY it goes into a direct loop. I'll try using CAAnimation or just a base case for my loop as I did.

Comment: Your guess is right, add `NSLog` to animation completion block, the log is out infinite.

Answer (score 3):

You should not use self in side the block. It will create a retain cycle. If it is necessary to call self create a weak self pointer. Code like this

```
__weak typeof(self) weakself = self;
[UIView animateWithDuration:4.0
                     delay:1.0
                     options: nil
                     animations:^{ 
                         // Animation PART 1
                         } 
                     completion:^(BOOL  completed){
                       [UIView animateWithDuration:4.0
                           animations:^{ 
                               // Animation PART 2
                               } 
                           completion:^(BOOL  completed){
                             [weakself animateView];
                           }
                         ];
                     }
     ];
```

But main issue with your code is you calling animateView recursively without any base case. So i consuming CPU cycles... do not use animateView without base case.

Comment: This seemed like a great idea, however, I still have my 100% CPU.. Any idea why?

Comment: That idea was for using self in block... But actually you are making recursive calls... animateView->animateView->animateView... which will cause stack over flow and also use CPU cycle... Recursion can only be use with base case... Base case means a case when you will not call method again... in your scenario you don't have any base case... and it goes in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try using timer

Write following line in your `viewDidLoad` or any where else from where you want animation to start.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:9 target:self selector:@selector(animateView) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
// 9 is total animation duration.....
```

update your animateView method as follows:

```
- (void)animateView{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:4.0
                     delay:1.0
                     options: nil
                     animations:^{ 
                         // Animation PART 1
                         } 
                     completion:^(BOOL  completed){
                       [UIView animateWithDuration:4.0
                           animations:^{ 
                               // Animation PART 2
                               } 
                           completion:^(BOOL  completed){

                           }
                         ];
                     }
     ]; 

}
```